# HTML5 Canvas; Image clipping and multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm fairly new to canvas and I'm having some issues.

I'm trying to accomplish one end goal: display two images in a single canvas; one image is the background, the other image is clipped to a PNG and appears over top.

I'm part way there but I've hit a wall and I don't know how to get past it.

I've create a jsFiddle for it at http://jsfiddle.net/jhp79yg9/

```js
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sources = {
        img1: 'https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11351598_1454928098145798_1274636321_n.jpg',
        img2: 'https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11379733_1139595366067106_273993739_n.jpg',
        mask: 'http://img12.deviantart.net/65e4/i/2013/003/6/6/png_floating_terrain_by_moonglowlilly-d5qb58m.png'
      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.img2, 0, 0, 240, 240);
        
        context.drawImage(images.mask, 20, 95, 500, 349);
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        context.drawImage(images.img1, 0, 0, 540, 540);

      });
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="540" height="540"></canvas>
```

In this example I've reduced the size of the first image to 140x140 from 540x540 just so I can tell if it's messing up, which it is.

What's happening is that it's not showing the second image, it's showing the 'img1' variable twice instead of showing 'img2' at all.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

I also can't tell, because it's rendering the same image, which is in the foreground and which is in the background. Help there as well would be appreciated (the clipped image should be in the foreground).

Thanks!

Comment: `img2` _is_ being drawn, but when `mask` is drawn over it, both are regarded as a unity and _then_ `img1` is drawn with `source-in` which replaces the pixels according to the value of the alpha chanel. `img1` is not being drawn twice. At least that’s the case for me (Firefox 39).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to cut out the mask from the current content and then draw the background behind the current content:

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.img2, 0, 0, 540, 540);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.drawImage(images.mask, 20, 95, 500, 349);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    context.drawImage(images.img1, 0, 0, 540, 540);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhp79yg9/6/

Comment: Thanks. This actually ended up working a bit better. Quick additional question, I've got a function swapping images on click, it works great for the image in the background but on the clipped image, it looks like it's putting the new image below the old one. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I wrote that backwards. The foreground is fine, the background doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't clearly understand what is your requirement, but making some assumptions I hope this will give you what you need

```
context.drawImage(images.img2, 100, 180, 350, 350);
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
context.drawImage(images.mask, 100, 180, 350, 350);
context.drawImage(images.img1, 0, 0, 540, 540);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhp79yg9/5/

Comment: I upvoted, although I understood the question so that the “Men’s Health” picture should be the background and the “Foo Fighters” should be the clipped part in the foreground.

Comment: @Xufox It's not a huge difference tho. He would just need to draw the images in a different order then.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! Turns out I was really close, yet so so far away. Thanks for your help!